# How to control/set permissions for a single user when using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have 1 SPA-Application which uses another WebApi. (ASP.NET Core) Both are running in Azure and I am able to authenticate the user against Azure AD B2C with OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow

Now I am asking myself how I can control the permissions of a single user. (Delete, Read, etc.) Do I have to work with claims? Do I have to leverage the graph API on the server side to check if a user has a certain permission? Can I use scopes? Where can I set the User <--> Scope relationship?

I have found several questions on SO, but I don't get the idea of how it should be done the right way? My current understanding is that I ask the authentication provider for certain scopes and I will get a token with this scopes which then can be checked by the API. But how do I manage which user can ask for which scopes?

I really have a problem to wrap my head around OAuth2 and permissions. Hope one can help me here.

Comment: Hi, @VSDekar . You can use Scope to define custom permissions in the token. E.g. When your Web API validate the JWT token with MSAL ,it will also validate the scope from the token.

Comment: And where do I set which scopes a user can ask for?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood. For one specific user, it's not possible for now. Because Azure AD B2C doesn't support application role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, for one specific user, you cannot assign  permissions/scopes to the user.

Because Azure AD B2C doesn't support Application Role. Generally, Azure AD B2C is for all users to access your App wit their account. Even Azure AD B2C can let you store and manage users, but it cannot assign different scopes/permissions to different users. Multiple scopes are the permissions granted to the resource. Multiple granted permissions will be separated by space.It's not for users access assignment.

If this important to you, you can upvote this idea in [**this Uservoice Page**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31997947-support-application-specific-roles-in-b2c). Azure  Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by creating [a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) of type `String` that stores a comma- or space-separated list of roles for a user.

You can then issue this custom attribute in the ID and access tokens or read it using the Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: How is access to custom attributes managed? If the user have access to edit those attributes them selfs, it can't be used to store permissions...

Comment: Hi @keft The ID and access tokens that are issued by Azure AD B2C don't allow access to these user attributes.